# REGEXP_SUBSTR - How to return value between ' '?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr

I need to return values from ' ' from below string (eg. for *psOrderByClause* I need value *xxx_seqno*). Additionally I've also need to return TRUE/FALSE values for some variables - there is no single quotes (eg. *pbUseDisplayName* I need *TRUE*).

I doesn't has to be in one query, there should be seperate query for every variable (eg. *psOrderByClause*, *psSeparator* etc.)

> prcCSVGenerator(pnRunKey => pnRunKey, pnConfigKey => pnConfigKey, psOrderByClause => 'xxx_seqno', psSeparator => '|', pbUseDisplayName => TRUE, pbUseWindowsEOL => TRUE);

For example from above string I need to return *xxx_seqno* in one query
and *TRUE* for another one

There is not always 'spaces' like above, sometimes it looks like "*psOrderByClause=> 'xxx_seqno'*" or "*psOrderByClause=>'xxx_seqno'*"

I'm not feeling Regex well, I've only something like this, but this returns all characters after psSeparator

> REGEXP_SUBSTR (text,'(psSeparator)(.*)',1,1,'i',2) regex

Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks

Comment: Example you posted doesn't match what you explained. I would imagine that you need to get a pipe character for psSeparator (as it is enclosed into single quotes), while you don't need anything for pBUseDisplayName because its TRUE isn't enclosed into single quotes. So, could you rephrase the question and match *image* with *words*? Also, to avoid confusion, say what *exactly* you want as a result. Is it only e.g. xxx_seqno or both psOrderByClause and its value, xxx_seqno.

Comment: Good point, I've updated my question. This should be more clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         value,
         q'[psOrderByClause\s*=>\s*('(''|[^'])*'|.*?)\s*(,|\))]',
         1,
         1,
         'i',
         1
       ) AS psOrderByClause,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         value,
         q'[psSeparator\s*=>\s*('(''|[^'])*'|.*?)\s*(,|\))]',
         1,
         1,
         'i',
         1
       ) AS psSeparator,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         value,
         q'[pbUseDisplayName\s*=>\s*('(''|[^'])*'|.*?)\s*(,|\))]',
         1,
         1,
         'i',
         1
       ) AS pbUseDisplayName,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         value,
         q'[pbUseWindowsEOL\s*=>\s*('(''|[^'])*'|.*?)\s*(,|\))]',
         1,
         1,
         'i',
         1
       ) AS pbUseWindowsEOL
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 'prcCSVGenerator(pnRunKey => pnRunKey, pnConfigKey => pnConfigKey, psOrderByClause => ''xxx_seqno'', psSeparator => ''|'', pbUseDisplayName => TRUE, pbUseWindowsEOL => TRUE);' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | PSORDERBYCLAUSE | PSSEPARATOR | PBUSEDISPLAYNAME | PBUSEWINDOWSEOL |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 'xxx_seqno' | '|' | TRUE | TRUE |

If you don't want the surrounding quotes then you can trim them as required.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5c4953d9d45475e540faff9b8fe84b9b)*